# #define in 'user-defined' section of target build settings, is not defined when xcode compiles code

Tags: xcode, llvm, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive, user-defined

I have a project, using the current version of **Xcode** and **llvm**.
I am doing a free and paid version of a game, so I have set up a preprocessor flag to do it.

For the paid version target I define `PAID_VERSION = 1`  (in the "**User-Defined**" section of **Build Settings**)

When I compile however the `PAID_VERSION` keeps coming up with undefined.
So my `#ifndef` and `#ifdef` directives build the free version of the app.

I have looked around **Stack Overflow** and **Google** and found no hints as to what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **Other C Flags** section add `-DPAID_VERSION=1`

This will define `PAID_VERSION` as `1`, equivalent to `#define PAID_VERSION 1` in code.